# Custom tab bar size

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitabbar

I'm making a custom tab bar, i add a 320x82 background image and for each tab i have a selection image with height 82. 
The problem is when a fit the tab bar frame with the background height (82) it gets a sort of shadow that its not on the original layout, and the selection images are not aligned. Here how i'm setting my tab bar:

```
    self.tabBatController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myView1, myView2, myView3, nil];

    UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
    [[UITabBar appearence] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

    CGRect viewFrame = tabBar.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -=41; //the correct position of the tab bar
    viewFrame.size.height = 82; //the correct height
    tabBar.frame = viewFrame;

    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

//this set of images are not aligned with the tabs
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1_selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1_unselected"]];

    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2_selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2_unselected"]];

    [item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3_selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3_unselected"]];
```

The tab is with the correct size, but it has this shadow and the non aligned selection images. How can i correct that?